# Proving: $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{x\}$ is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Determine whereas $\{x\}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open or closed?

Because $\{x\}$ is just a point there is no $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subset$ $\{x\}$ so $\{x\}$ is not open

To show that  $\{x\}$ is close we will need to show that $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{x\}$ is open, that is for all $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{x\}$ there is $\delta>0$ such that 
$B(y,\delta)\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{x\}$

How in general do we approach those questions? is it like finding $\delta$ as an expression of $\epsilon$ in limits?

Comment: Just take $\delta$ to be half the distance from $y$ to $x$.

Comment: I think you should specify the topology

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti sorry it is in R^n

Comment: @TonyK but then $||y-x||<\frac{||y-x||}{2}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvotes on this.

Comment: @gbox yeah I understand it, but what happens if you consider e.g. $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the trivial topology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\mathbb R^n \backslash \{x\}$ is given 
all $p$ in $\mathbb R^n$ for which $0 < \|p-x\| < \infty$.

This is an open set under any metric topology.

The complement of an open set is a closed set.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a hint**

A finite subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is closed since all the convergent sequences are stationnary.

Answer (score 0):

Direct proof that $\{x\}$ is closed (so any convergent sequence with elements in $\{x\}$ has its limit in $\{x\})$:

Let $\{x_n\}\subseteq\{x\}$ a convergent sequence. Then we have $x_n=x$, so $x_n\rightarrow x\in\{x\}$. So ${x}$ is closed.

Alternative proof: $\{x\}$ is closed iff $R^n\backslash\{x\}$ is open, so any point in $R^n\backslash\{x\}$ has a neigborhood contained in $R^n\backslash\{x\}$:

Let $y\in \mathbb R^n$ and $0<\delta<d(x,y)$ where $d(x,y)$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$ in whichever metric you are using.

Then $B(y,\delta)\subset\mathbb R^n\backslash\{x\}$

so $R^n\backslash\{x\}$ is open.